# Xkb: Switch Overlay vs HotKeys

Tags: linux, layout, keyboard

I'm trying to configure xkb to select each keyboard layouts with unique hotkey (en = Win+1, de = Win+2, jp = Win+3)

```
    replace key <I156> { [NoSymbol], actions[Group1] = [ LockGroup(group=1) ] };
    replace key <I157> { [NoSymbol], actions[Group1] = [ LockGroup(group=2) ] };
    replace key <I210> { [NoSymbol], actions[Group1] = [ LockGroup(group=3) ] };

    replace key <LWIN> {
        symbols[Group1] = [ Super_L ],
        actions[Group1] = [ SetControls(controls=overlay1)  ]
    };

    key <AE01> { overlay1 = <I156> };
    key <AE02> { overlay1 = <I157> };
    key <AE03> { overlay1 = <I210> };
```

But it breaks hotkeys with Win key (e.g. Win + T). Is it possible to configure key to switch overlay that does not break hotkeys?

Answer (score 0):

I tried something very similar but also with no luck. I ended up simply binding system-wide shortcuts to setxkbmap commands. In my case:

Super+F1 = setxkbmap de
Super+F2 = setxkbmap us -variant colemak
etc.

I'm on a Xfce desktop, which has a handy utility for keyboard shortcuts but there are other ways to do this on other desktops.

Cheers,
Os